How to add eventlistener to created buttons?
I'm making a todo list that includes a check button on every todo, but I don't know exactly how to add an event listener so that every button when clicked changes only that specific button's color (which I plan to do by adding the class checked-btn to the respective button) and create an event listener every time a new todo is added.
On JS I tried making it by adding the event listener when creating the element and adding it to the DOM:


// localStorage mock
const localStorage = { s: {}, setItem (k, v) { console.log('set', k, String(v)); this.s[k] = String(v); }, getItem (k) { console.log('get', k, this.s[k]); return this.s[k] ?? null; } };

let project = "default";
let currentTodo = 1;
appendTodo(currentTodo);

function appendTodo(currentTodo) {
  const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  todoDiv.classList.add("todo-div");
  todoDiv.id = `${project} ${currentTodo}`;

  const btnDiv = document.createElement("div");
  btnDiv.classList.add("btn-div");
  todoDiv.appendChild(btnDiv);

  const checkBtn = document.createElement("button");
  checkBtn.classList.add("check-btn");
  checkBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem(`${project} ${currentTodo} check`)) {
      checkBtn.classList.add("checked-btn");
      localStorage.setItem(`${project} ${currentTodo} check`, false);
    } else {
      checkBtn.classList.remove("checked-btn");
      localStorage.setItem(`${project} ${currentTodo} check`, true);
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem(`${project} ${currentTodo} check`, false);
  const checkImg = document.createElement("img")
  checkImg.src = "../src/img/check.png";
  checkImg.alt = `Check ${localStorage.getItem(`${project} ${currentTodo} title`)} from ${project}`;
  checkImg.classList.add("icon");
  checkBtn.appendChild(checkImg);
  btnDiv.appendChild(checkBtn);

  const editBtn = document.createElement("button");
  editBtn.classList.add("edit-btn");
  const editImg = document.createElement("img")
  editImg.src = "../src/img/edit.png";
  editImg.alt = `Edit ${localStorage.getItem(`${project} ${currentTodo} title`)} from ${project}`;
  editImg.classList.add("icon");
  editBtn.appendChild(editImg);
  btnDiv.appendChild(editBtn);

  const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
  deleteBtn.classList.add("delete-btn");
  const deleteImg = document.createElement("img")
  deleteImg.src = "../src/img/delete.png";
  deleteImg.alt = `Delete ${localStorage.getItem(`${project} ${currentTodo} title`)} from ${project}`;
  deleteImg.classList.add("icon");
  deleteBtn.appendChild(deleteImg);
  btnDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  const todos = document.getElementById("todos");
  todos.appendChild(todoDiv);
}
.todo-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 32fr;
  width: 75%;
}

.btn-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
}

.btn-div>* {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn-div>*:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check-btn:hover,
.edit-btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.delete-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(210, 1, 1);
}

.delete-btn {
  background-color: rgb(255, 42, 42);
}

.icon {
  width: 100%;
}
<div id="todos"></div>



The button and the information of the todo are added correctly but the button doesn't do anything (also I'm not sure if saving the check state of every button is necessary).

Are you sure you've added the button to the DOM?

Yes, the buttons are appended to the DOM (check, edit and delete), I didn't add the part of appending them for sake of brevity.

Can you create a minimal reproducible using the snippet tool (the icon button with the <> symbol)?

You might consider event delegation; "...you can bind an event handler to a single parent element, and that handler will get executed whenever the event occurs on any of its child nodes..."

I tried my best to do a minimal reproducible code, hopefully is good enough, still will look into event delegation.

Have you tried adding an argument to the event handler to get the event that is being passed around and then use event.currentTarget to grab the element that's triggering the event?

I forgot some parts of my code, oops, should be better now.

The strings "true" and "false" are both truthy

@l3l_aze you sure about that? The bug in their code causes it to always enter the if condition, trying to add the class, never removing it. There's also no styling for .checked-btn so nothing happens visually

@Phil Now that I've managed to run the example, no. Lol. Sorry. It is still broken after fixing the check of the value in localStorage, but all it needs is to swap the call to set true and false, which is not what I thought was wrong.
